# Grab UIWebView Page Title as NSString

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsstring

I'm attempting to obtain the Title of a loaded web page via JavaScipt and place that as the title of a UIActionSheet as so:

[image: UIActionSheet]

What I have currently in my **ViewController.m**:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *webTitle = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
}

- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
    // webTitle.text receives errors
    UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:webTitle delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Share...", @"Bookmarks", @"Read Later", @"Add to Bookmarks", @"Settings", nil];
    actionsheet.actionSheetStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Action Menu opened");
}
```

EDIT: I'm also receiving these warnings.

[image: Warnings]

EDIT2: Evaluating the code via javascript alert works fine.

[image: Evaluation]

Comment: What happens if you try to `alert` the title in your javascript string?

Comment: Yes, so instead of evaluating the javascript string `document.title`, try evaluating `alert(document.title)`.

Comment: Seems to work fine, check out my latest edit.

Comment: It appears you are overwriting your instance variable. Try removing the `NSString *` qualifier from your webTitle, in your `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` method.

Comment: Yes, webTitle is local variable only visible in the webViewDidFinishLoad method's scope

Comment: Thank you, getting rid of the NSString qualifier worked. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you declared the `webTitle` inside `webViewDidFinishLoad:` it is a local variable and any value you assign it is only valid in the scope of this particular method.

Since you want to use `webTitle` outside of the scope of `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, inside `showActionSheet:` you need a variable that is visible to both methods.

You need to declare an instance variable in your `webViewController` to hold the value of the page title. Then you will set its value inside `webViewDidFinishLoad:` like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    webTitle = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
}
```

The code above assumes you named your instance variable `webTitle`

If you already have this instance variable in your controller and have redeclared it by mistake inside `webVieDidFinishLoad:`, just remove the `NSString *` from the assignment line.